# Custom Taxonomy Hierarchy when checked

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

i have a small issue with the custom taxonomy in wordpress.

I have a hierarchical custom taxonomy in my admin that look like that :

```
Taxonomy 1
Taxonomy 2
 -Taxonomy 2.1
 -Taxonomy 2.2
Taxonomy 3
 -Taxonomy 3.1
```

When i select Taxonomy 2.1 and i update my post, when i go back see my metabox that contain ma taxonomy, it now look like that :

```
Taxonomy 1
Taxonomy 2.1
Taxonomy 2
 -Taxonomy 2.2
Taxonomy 3
 -Taxonomy 3.1
```

And when i select Taxonomy 2 and Taxonomy 2.1 and i update my post, when i go back, i look like that :

```
Taxonomy 1
Taxonomy 2.2
Taxonomy 2
 -Taxonomy 2.1
Taxonomy 3
 -Taxonomy 3.1
```

Why my taxonomy don't keep the hierarchical order? Actually, they keep there order in the backend, but visually they don't! How can i fix that? THX!

Comment: what have you set your 'orderby' to?

Comment: No... they dont even talk about 'orderby' in the codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Comment: So thats to register the taxonomy. What about when you query it?

Comment: When i query it, they keep there hierarchy ... it only a visual problem... visually they don't keep there order in the admin

Comment: This might help - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21798/sort-custom-taxonomy-terms-in-admin-by-custom-order

Comment: Thx, but it not helping me sry...